# UICollectionView removing selected cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I would like the delete the selected cels in the `UICollectionView`.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *cardTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cardTableArry; // of Card and datamodel
```

you can get the paths of them using as an array

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [[self cardTable] indexPathsForSelectedItems];
```

you can't `[[self cardTable] removeObjectsAtIndexes: indexPaths];` 
as you need a `NSIndexSet`.

is there a way to convert the `NSArray *indexPaths` to a `NSIndexSet` ore do i need to
do somting intierly difrend to get what i wand

I would like to convert the array in a `NSIndexSet`

```
[[self cardTableArry] deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: [[self cardTable] indexPathsForSelectedItems]];
```

Comment: What does not work with `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:`? Are you also deleting the items from your datamodel?

Comment: You always need to delete it from your datamodel. The collectionview is nothing more than a view to your data.The `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:` allows you to update the screen without using `reloadData`. Ergo: you want to do both.

Comment: do i need to create a array that will ceap trak of the selected cells or can the NSArray *indexPaths = [[self cardTable] indexPathsForSelectedItems]; be converted to a NSIndexSet that can be used to delete the cells at the data model?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
- (void) removeCardsFromTable: (NSArray *) indexPaths {
    NSMutableArray *cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger selectedLoop = 0; selectedLoop < 3; selectedLoop++) {
        NSIndexPath *card = [indexPaths objectAtIndex: selectedLoop];
        [cards addObject: [[self cardTable] objectAtIndex: [card item]]];
    }
    for (NSInteger selectedLoop = 0; selectedLoop < 3; selectedLoop++) {
        [[self cardTable] removeObject: [cards objectAtIndex: selectedLoop]];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bunk: selecting the code lines and pressing `CTRL+K` will do magics. :)